# How to change cursor size in PyQt5?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, mouse-cursor

I want to implement brush cursor like in most image editors when cursor is a circle that change its size according to brush size. I've read the docs and found only `setShape` method, but no `setSize`. Is it possible in Qt to change cursor size?

Comment: If you use the [`QCursor(const QPixmap &pixmap, ...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcursor.html#QCursor-3) constructor you can more or less have any cursor you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pixmap = QPixmap("image.png")  # Replace with the path to your custom cursor image, brush in your case
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(30, 30)  # Set the desired size
cursor = QCursor(pixmap)
self.setCursor(cursor)
```

you can change the size and the "form" of your cursor in PyQt5 by creating a pixmap and then assigning in to your cursor

Comment: Your solution worked fine for me, but after a while using it, I found out that it is a bit glitchy for my usecase: if you set size less than 0 you get pixmap error (makes sense) and if you set size bigger than 255 it  starts to visualize cursor's pixmap transparent background (I used 32x32 png). So now, for brush, instead of reassigning standard cursor,  I just hide it and draw ellipse on mouse move event, which gives much more robust and pleasing UX.